# Excel formular with SEQUENCE that create a formular

Tags: excel-formula, sequence

Is it possible to write a formular in excel that generates a formular, I do not have an example yet, but I would like to insert a SEQUENCE in the formular, and thereby save a lot of work, I just need some kind of example :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy one:

```
 =INDEX(A:A,5)
```

will give you the value in **A5** and :

```
 =INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(5))
```

will give you the values in **A1** through **A5**